# Can I enable a universal minimise-on-close?

Tags: window, ubuntu-gnome, minimize

Is it possible to configure GNOME so that when I click the "X" button on a window, or select "Quit" from the topbar menu, the window is minimised rather than closed?

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible.

You can configure GNOME to not show the close button in the standard title bar, but this will not apply to all apps on the system. "Quit" in the application's menu, is an internal function.

Comment: do you mind explaining how to remove the X?